# Select n keywords from list

Tags: python, list, random

I need to select only a certain number of (random) keywords from the list at a time and not make an API call with all the keys as is the case now.
How can I proceed?

```
    # Search keywords definition
keywords = ["Televisori", "Notebook", "Tablet", "Apple", "Samsung", "Smartwatch", "Auricolari Bluetooth", "Fotocamera",
            "Videocamera"]

# run bot function
def run_bot(bot, keywords):
    # shuffling keywords list
    random.shuffle(keywords)

    # start loop
    while True:
        try:
            items_full = []

            # iterate over keywords
            for el in keywords:
                # iterate over pages
                for i in range(1, 10):

                    items = search_items(el, CATEGORY, item_page=i)

                    # api time limit for another http request is 1 second
                    time.sleep(1)

                    items_full.append(items)

            # concatenate all results
            items_full = list(chain(*items_full))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `n` random elements from the list like this:

```
import random
keywords = ["Televisori", "Notebook", "Tablet", "Apple", "Samsung", "Smartwatch", "Auricolari Bluetooth", "Fotocamera",
            "Videocamera"]

random.shuffle(keywords)
n = 10
new_list = keywords[:n]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select a number of random items from the list, you can use `random.choices()`. In this example, it will select 4 random keywords:

```
import random
keywords = ["Televisori", "Notebook", "Tablet", "Apple", "Samsung", "Smartwatch", "Auricolari Bluetooth", "Fotocamera",
            "Videocamera"]
random_keywords = random.choices(keywords, k=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You can use `random.sample` with any value in **`range(1,len(population))`** you like:

***(random.sample Chooses k unique random elements from a population)***

```
>>> import random
>>> keywords = ["Televisori", "Notebook", "Tablet", "Apple", "Samsung", "Smartwatch", "Auricolari Bluetooth", "Fotocamera","Videocamera"]

>>> random.sample(keywords,5)
['Fotocamera', 'Videocamera', 'Notebook', 'Televisori', 'Samsung']

>>> random.sample(keywords,2)
['Televisori', 'Smartwatch']
```